# "The furniture items placed in guest rooms include a sofa, writing table, cupboard, luggage rack"— Can I use "furniture" instead of "furniture items"?

Tags: difference, plural-forms, uncountable-nouns

[books.google.ru](https://books.google.ru/books?id=QaSoDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT115&lpg=PT115&dq=%22The%20furniture%20items%20placed%20in%20guest%20rooms%20include%20a%20sofa,%20writing%20table,%20cupboard,%20luggage%20rack%22&source=bl&ots=5diwSKs3mC&sig=ACfU3U0x4SYJSl5u_t0c8eILIS5sL3bC5Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDn7aSk_uCAxUXKxAIHeUVDVQQ6AF6BAgJEAM):
**(1)** *The furniture **items** placed in guest rooms include a sofa, writing table, cupboard, luggage rack etc.*

I wonder if I can use just "*furniture*" here instead of "*furniture items*":
**(2)** *The furniture placed in guest rooms includes a sofa, writing table, cupboard, luggage rack etc.*

Is (2) correct?
If it is, is there any difference between (1) and (2)?

Comment: Note that *[furniture] **items*** is a plural noun phrase, which is why it gets the plural verb form ***include***. But if you change to just ***furniture***, that's a singular (mass) noun, so the verb form must be changed to ***includes***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(2) is correct and more idiomatic.

"Furniture" is a mass noun. "Furniture items" sounds like a store that has an inventory of items and needs to qualify some of them as furniture (i.e., items belonging to the furniture category).